# Published Android App not showing up in Google Play at all

Tags: android, google-play

I made a rudimentary Android App primarily for some friends and even when I type in its exact 3-word title, it doesn't show up in any of the results.

This is puzzling since the status says "Published" in the developer console for at least a day or two. It's my third public app release in Google Play and the first time I've experienced this problem.

The name of the app is "Team Stealth Test" by Minty Apps (Sorry I swear I don't care about advertising it to you all. It's just a quick side project not in it for the downloads)

Has anyone else experienced this? For all my other apps if you type in the exact name it always shows up even if the name is not unique so I'm wondering if I just got unlucky. Thanks

Comment: I have a same problem but my app appeared through 3 - 7 days.

Comment: Add something to description or change something submit again

Comment: Thanks for the responses I had changed the title form group test already I'll try adding to the description

Answer (score 1):

It may take a few days for Google Play to index your app and allow it to be found by searching in the Google Play store. If it does not appear in 2-3 days contact support and let them know, they will be more than happy to help.